# Select from XML, Build datastructure

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to build a datastructure based on xml content.

The structure looks like that:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

The XML looks like that:

```
<Table name="testTable">
<Row>
  <Column name="test01" value="2029" />
  <Column name="test02" value="2029" />
</Row>
<Row>
  <Column name="test01" value="2029" />
  <Column name="test02" value="2029" />
</Row>
</Table>
<Table name="testTable01">
<Row>
  <Column name="test01" value="2029" />
  <Column name="test02" value="2029" />
</Row>
<Row>
  <Column name="test01" value="2029" />
  <Column name="test02" value="2029" />
</Row>
</Table>
```

It should result in something like that:

```
Dictionary<tableName, List<Dictionary<columnName, columnValue>>>
```

It's no problem to do that with some nested foreach-loops, but I'm searching for a way to do that "in one line" with the LINQ extension methods. How could I do that?

Comment: I only tried the nested loops and that worked. But now I'am searching for a "more elegant" solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var tables = doc.Descendants("Table")
                .ToDictionary(t => (string) t.Attribute("name"),
                              t => ExtractRowsFromTable(t));

...

private static List<Dictionary<string, string>> ExtractRowsFromTable(XElement table)
{
    return table.Elements("Row")
                .Select(row => row.Elements("Column")
                                  .ToDictionary(c => (string) c.Attribute("name"),
                                                c => (string) c.Attribute("value"))
                .ToList();
}
```

You *could* do all of this in one line, basically inlining `ExtractRowsFromTable` - but I *really* wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
string xml = 
        @"<Root>
            <Table name=""testTable"">
                <Row>
                    <Column name=""test01"" value=""2029"" />
                    <Column name=""test02"" value=""2029"" />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column name=""test01"" value=""2029"" />
                    <Column name=""test02"" value=""2029"" />
                </Row>
            </Table>
            <Table name=""testTable2"">
                <Row>
                    <Column name=""test01"" value=""2029"" />
                    <Column name=""test02"" value=""2029"" />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Column name=""test01"" value=""2029"" />
                    <Column name=""test02"" value=""2029"" />
                </Row>
            </Table>
        </Root>";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var table = xDoc
        .Descendants("Table")
        .Select(t => new
        {
            Name = t.Attribute("name").Value,
            Rows = t.Descendants("Row")
                    .Select(r=> r.Descendants("Column")
                                 .ToDictionary(c=>c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                               c=>c.Attribute("value").Value))
                    .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a closer look at your solution.

Comment: Currently you're building a list as the "outer" part, when the OP requested a dictionary. Easy enough to fix, of course :)